# Oracle Apex 19.2 - How to add a sql query in javascript function

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

There is a way in which I can add an sql query in a javascript function.

here is my function :

```
function put_selected_value(sel_value) {

$x('P130_SEL_RAD').value='SELECT salary FROM employees WHERE employee_id = ' + sel_value;
}
```

In this case the P130_SEL_RAD shows me the string SELECT salary FROM employees WHERE...

But I would like to show the result of the query in the P130_SEL_RAD item.

And Thank you.

Comment: If you want to run SQL from Javascript, you need to call an AJAX process. See e.g. http://www.apexexplorer.com/calling-ajax-call-back-process-in-oracle-apex-using-javascript/

Comment: This question reads like, "how can I add SQL injection into my application"? What if I changed the query to `delete from employees`?